# Working with a .dl_ file in visual studio

Tags: c#

I've sent over a .dl_ file which I need to reference within my visual studio project, from what I have been told the .dl_ file contains 1 interface, 1 model and 1 XML file.

I've never worked with .dl_ before so I'm slightly confused on how I go about getting such information as mentioned above in to my solution, I have googled this but all I get back is information about what is it not how to reference / use it.

I have tried right clicking on references > add reference > browse to .dl_ location and tried adding it but I get the error "Could not be added. Please mark sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"

Comment: .dl_?  Do you mean .dll?  how did you receive the file?  Via email?  Is it possible they renamed the file from .dll to .dl_ so the attachment wouldn't be stripped by the server?

Comment: @Tim the file extension is in fact .dl_ I received it via email yes. I never thought of the renaming situation. But I gave it ago and seemed to of worked. Thanks

Comment: Hmm....have you asked the folks that sent it to you?  That's a really weird file extension.

Comment: I had never seen a file extension like that before either, but renaming it from .dl_ to .dll worked, and I was able to reference it in my project and call the methods inside.

Comment: Why are you asking us? Why don't you ask the person that sent you the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dl_` file sounds like a file that was compressed. Microsoft compresses a lot of their system files on their installation media. To decompress it, you use [Expand](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722332(v=ws.10).aspx), a Microsoft command line utility. To expand your file, open a command window and type this:

```
C:\> CD\
C:\> CD MyDirectory
C:\MyDirectory> Expand MyFile.dl_ MyFile.dll
```

Replace `MyDirectory` with whatever directory your `dl_` file is in. This will create the DLL file, then you use it like you would a normal dll.

Another possibility is that your friend simply renamed the file from `.dll` to `.dl_`. A lot of email clients will not allow you to send an email with a `.dll` or `.exe` attachment. This is for security reasons. So a common way to get around this is to rename the extension. Ask your friend if he did this.

Answer (score 0):

Most installers store dll files as dl_ inside them.
But if the extension is dll that doesn't mean the file is an assembly, it could be a native windows library.
Ask the sender about the file.